# Possível problema de buffer em nasm

Tags: linux, algoritmo, ubuntu, nasm

Escrevi um programa em Nasm que deve ler os dados do paciente para que seja feito o cálculo do IMC, porém, o sistema automaticamente escreve "Di" antes de eu sequer encostar no teclado. Nâo sei mais o que fazer, apelei até para o chatgpt, porém eu e meu códigos apenas ficamos ainda mais confusos.

```
_start:
; Limpa o buffer de nome
call clear_buffer

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, prompt_nome
mov edx, 30
int 0x80

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, nome
mov edx, 255
int 0x80

; Limpa o buffer de entrada após ler o nome
call clear_buffer
```

No console, ele sai assim:

Digite o nome do paciente: Di
Digite a idade do paciente: DIdade inválida. Digite uma idade válida (maior que zero):
Digite o nome do paciente: Di

Abaixo está o código completo, mas creuio que o erro esteja especificamente na parte citado acima. Ficarei grato caso alguém possa jogar uma luz, eu realmente nâo enxergo onde errei. Obrigado!

```
section .data
    prompt_nome db "Digite o nome do paciente: ", 0
    prompt_idade db "Digite a idade do paciente: ", 0
    prompt_peso db "Digite o peso do paciente (em kg): ", 0
    prompt_altura db "Digite a altura do paciente (em metros): ", 0
    mensagem_imc db "O IMC do paciente e: %.2f", 0
    mensagem_continuar db "Deseja fazer outro calculo (S/N)? ", 0
    newline db 10, 0   ; Caractere de nova linha
    buffer db 255       ; Buffer de entrada
    float_buffer db "0.00", 0

section .bss
    nome resb 255
    idade resb 255
    peso resb 255
    altura resb 255

section .text
global _start

; Função para limpar o buffer de entrada
clear_buffer:
    mov eax, 0      ; syscall number para sys_read
    mov ebx, 0      ; descritor de arquivo stdin (entrada padrão)
    mov ecx, buffer ; endereço do buffer
    mov edx, 255    ; tamanho máximo de leitura
    int 0x80
    ret

_start:
    ; Limpa o buffer de nome
    call clear_buffer

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, prompt_nome
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    ; Exibe uma nova linha
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, newline
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    ; Lê o nome do paciente
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, nome
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    ; Remove caracteres indesejados "Di" no início do nome
    mov esi, nome  ; ESI aponta para o nome lido
    mov edi, nome  ; EDI apontará para o novo nome sem "Di"

    remove_di:
        mov al, [esi]  ; Carrega o próximo caractere do nome
        cmp al, 0      ; Verifica se chegou ao final da string
        je done        ; Se chegou ao final, saia

        cmp al, 'D'
        je check_i
        mov [edi], al  ; Copia o caractere para a nova string
        inc edi
        inc esi
        jmp remove_di

    check_i:
        inc esi         ; Avança para o próximo caractere (após 'i')
        jmp remove_di

    done:
    ; Adiciona o terminador de string à nova string
    mov byte [edi], 0

    ; Exibe o prompt e lê a idade do paciente
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, prompt_idade
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    ; Lê a idade do paciente, verificando se é numérica
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, 0
    mov edi, idade
    mov ecx, 255

    read_age_loop:
        mov edx, 1
        int 0x80

        ; Verifica se o caractere lido é um dígito (0-9)
        cmp byte [edi], '0'
        jl invalid_age
        cmp byte [edi], '9'
        jg invalid_age

        inc edi
        loop read_age_loop

    ; Converte a string da idade em um número
    call atoi
    
    ; Verifica se a idade é válida (por exemplo, maior que zero)
    cmp eax, 0
    jle invalid_age

    invalid_age:
    ; Exibe uma mensagem de erro
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, invalid_age_message
    mov edx, invalid_age_message_length
    int 0x80

    ; Limpa o buffer de idade
    mov eax, 0
    mov edi, idade
    mov ecx, 255
    rep stosb

    ; Exibe uma nova linha
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, newline
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    ; Volta para pedir a idade novamente
    jmp _start

    invalid_age_message db "Idade inválida. Digite uma idade válida (maior que zero): ", 0
    invalid_age_message_length equ $ - invalid_age_message

    ; Exibe o prompt e le o peso do paciente
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, prompt_peso
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, peso
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    ; Exibe o prompt e le a altura do paciente
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, prompt_altura
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, altura
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    ; Converte as strings em numeros
    call atof
    fstp qword [float_buffer]

    ; Calcula o IMC
    fld qword [float_buffer]
    fild dword [peso]
    fdiv
    fild dword [altura]
    fmul
    fdiv
    fstp qword [float_buffer]

    ; Exibe o resultado do IMC
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, mensagem_imc
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    ; Exibe uma nova linha
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, newline
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    ; Pergunta se o usuario deseja fazer outro calculo
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, mensagem_continuar
    mov edx, 30
    int 0x80

    ; Le a resposta do usuario (S ou N)
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, buffer
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    cmp byte [buffer], 'N'
    je exit
    cmp byte [buffer], 'n'
    je exit

    ; Limpa os buffers e reinicia o calculo
    mov eax, 0
    mov edi, nome
    mov ecx, 255
    rep stosb

    mov edi, idade
    rep stosb

    mov edi, peso
    rep stosb

    mov edi, altura
    rep stosb

    jmp _start

exit:
    ; Saida do programa
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80

atoi:
    push    ebx             ; preserve ebx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    ecx             ; preserve ecx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    edx             ; preserve edx on the stack to be restored after function runs
    push    esi             ; preserve esi on the stack to be restored after function runs
    mov     esi, eax        ; move pointer in eax into esi (our number to convert)
    mov     eax, 0          ; initialise eax with decimal value 0
    mov     ecx, 0          ; initialise ecx with decimal value 0

atof:
    ; Conversao de string para float
    ; Argumento: [esp]
    ; Resultado: ST(0) (ponto flutuante)
    fldz                    ; ST(0) = 0
    fld dword [esp]         ; ST(0) = string para inteiro
    fsub                    ; ST(0) = ST(0) - 0 = ST(0) (mantem o valor original)
    fild dword [esp]        ; ST(0) = inteiro para float
    fsub                    ; ST(0) = ST(0) - 0 = ST(0) (mantem o valor original)
    fdiv                    ; ST(0) = ST(0) / ST(1) (divisao por 1)
    fadd                    ; ST(0) = ST(0) + ST(1) (soma com zero)
    ret
```